# JQPlot - datapoints not lining up with ticks?

Tags: jquery, jqplot

I'm having trouble making this simple thing happen. I have this loop adding values to my arrays:

```
for(i = 0; i < sections; i++){
    datapointsUser[i] = [i+1, USER_NotesTaken[i]];
    datapointsAverage[i] = [i+1, AVERAGE_NotesTaken[i]];
    datapointsTopStudent[i] = [i+1, TOP_NotesTaken[i]];
}
```

Yet when I graph this on my jqplot, the datapoints don't appear on the set of integers for the x axis. They look to be about halfway between each integer, despite the fact that I should have given them integer x values from this loop. Why are the values not landing on the ticks? I'll put the code for my graph below. Thanks!

```
$.jqplot('statgraph', [datapointsUser, datapointsAverage, datapointsTopStudent], {
        axes: {
            xaxis: {
                numberTicks: sections,
                tickInterval: 1,
            },
            yaxis: {
                numberTicks: 16,
            },
        },

    });
```

Code for filling out graphed arrays:

```
// Dummy data
USER_NotesTaken = [3, 10, 4, 9, 5];
AVERAGE_NotesTaken = [7, 3, 1, 7, 9];
TOP_NotesTaken = [5, 8, 12, 13, 14];

// Sections variable is 5    
for(i = 0; i < sections; i++){
    datapointsUser[i] = [i+1, USER_NotesTaken[i]];
    datapointsAverage[i] = [i+1, AVERAGE_NotesTaken[i]];
    datapointsTopStudent[i] = [i+1, TOP_NotesTaken[i]];
}
```

Comment: Can you please show the arrays after they were built by the loop (with the actual values in them), it can help look for an answer. Thanks.

Comment: Just added them at the end of the question, thanks for the heads up! There's no actual client-server interaction currently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop that creates your data make all of the data arrays with the same number of ticks (5 in this specific example). The `section` variable is also the same as the ticks number. You don't need to "tell" this info to the graph engine, because it will generate it from the arrays automatically.

#### Summary:

You dont need the extra `xaxis` info. Remove `numberTicks` and `tickInterval` from the `xaxis` section, and your ticks will be aligned perfectly.

#### Working Code:

This is an aligned graph with the same data you've provided:

```
$.jqplot('statgraph',  [[[1,3],[2,10],[3,4],[4,9],[5,5]], [[1,7],[2,3],[3,1],[4,7],    
[5,9]], [[1,5],[2,8],[3,12],[4,13],[5,14]]],
{     
 axes: {
        xaxis: {
         
        //REMOVED EVERYTHING FROM HERE, YOU CAN REMOVE THE ENTIRE xaxis brackets.
        
        },
        yaxis: {
            numberTicks: 16
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that does work in terms of lining up the points, but what if I only want the graph's x-axis displaying 1-2-3-4-5? Right now it is displaying 0.5 intervals, as well as above and below 1.

Comment: Add inside the `xaxis` brackets this line: `pad: 0`, that should cancel the above and below.

Comment: However, what happens if you want to limit the tick number? The values seem off when that happens. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12822514/jqplot-points-not-correct-when-numberticks-set